# matplotlib: Color 2D line by logarithmic colorbar value used to color scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to color a line which connects a scatter plot colored by a 3rd variable (the third variable is identical for all scatter points; I will have multiple scatterplots with different 3rd variables in the end). I need the color of the line to match the scatterpoints and the colorbar needs to be log scaled. I am having trouble extracting the RGBA log-normalized value used to color the scatter points in order to color the line by that value. Example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

color = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

#Fake data
a = np.arange(0,10,1)
b = np.arange(10,20,1)
d = [100]*10

maxval=1000.0
minval=10.0

#Normalize array to limits of colorbar
l=d[1]
normalized= (l/(maxval-minval))

#Check if Nan (I have some NaN's).
#Returns the colormap value
check = np.isnan(np.sum(normalized))
cmapvalue=[]
if check==True:
    cmapvalue=g
else:
    cmapvalue=color(normalized)

#Plot scatter and line, line needs to be colored by RGBA value used to color scatter points
plt.scatter(a, b, c=d, cmap=color, norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmax=maxval,       vmin=minval), zorder=2, s=50)
plt.plot(a,b, c=cmapvalue, zorder=1, lw=4)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please also provid `d`? Or provide an appropriate substitute?

Comment: updated with d... apologies

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you scale your values linearly (manually). But in the call to scatter you pass a logarithmic scaling class. Instead of just passing it, you can directly use it to normalize the values for your call to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

#Fake data
a = np.arange(0,10,1)
b = np.arange(10,20,1)
d = [50]*10

# define vmin and vmax
maxval=1000.0
minval=10.0

# build up colormap and normalizer
colormap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmax=maxval, vmin=minval)

# helper function to plot the line and the scatter data
def plot_my_scatterdata(x, y, d):
    if np.any(np.isnan(d)):
        color = 'g'
    else:
        # use the colormap and the normalization instance!
        color = colormap(norm(d[0]))

    plt.scatter(a, b, c=d, cmap=colormap, norm=norm, zorder=2, s=50)
    plt.plot(a,b, '-', color=color, zorder=1, lw=4)

plot_my_scatterdata(a, b, d)
d = [100]*10
b += 1
plot_my_scatterdata(a, b, d)
d = [500]*10
b += 1
plot_my_scatterdata(a, b, d)
d[0] = np.nan
b += 1
plot_my_scatterdata(a, b, d)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]